# onBeforeSaveUser event does not fire if basic user fields do not validate

Tags: form, validation

I have additional fields I check for in the `onBeforeSaveUser` event and add the errors to the errors array. The problem is my code doesnt even run if they miss the main fields or if the email is already in use or something like that... I would like to return ALL validation errors, not just the default field errors first.

If I go to my form and just press submit without filling anything it out it only complains about the username, email address and password. If I just fill those fields out, then it comes back and complains about all my other fields (a la my event handler). This is unexpected behavior. Am I doing something wrong or is there a way to address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it's unexpected behavior, but for Craft 2 it won't change.

[Craft 3](https://craftcms.com/3) had a major overhaul of its event system and validation workflow where it works as you'd expect, though.

Comment: Boo! Oh well, at least I can stop wasting my time trying to figure out how to make it work how I want. I guess I'll have to upgrade to craft 3 once its production ready.

Comment: Thats a big ouch!
What about via ajax? Can we get to append errors this way? e.g. http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19707/ajax-front-end-user-registration-form-not-displaying-macro-errorlist

Comment: Just checked this out in ajax as per: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19707/ajax-front-end-user-registration-form-not-displaying-macro-errorlist 
This looks promising